# Firefox not working Ubuntu 14.04 LTS : libXrender.so.1 and XPCOMGlueLoad error

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I have installed Firefox 45.2.0 ESR in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but it is not loading.

Installed version:

```
    $ file /opt/firefox/firefox
    /opt/firefox/firefox: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64,
 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=b74588285e9703d20270c7fc0e5a2ba3690004b9, stripped
```

Error on launch:

```
$ firefox
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libxul.so:
libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I tried to update libdbus-glib-1-2 but of no help. Any guidance would help.